# How to find a principal part of a function at a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, laurent-series

On the page 175 of the paper provided below, principle part of of a generating function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2-e^z}$$

at its pole $z_0=\ln2$ is computed to be $$ f_p(z)=\frac{-1}{2(z-\ln2)}.$$

From my knowledge, the principle part is the part of the Laurant series which's input goes from $-\infty$ to $0$. Thus my question is how did the paper find such a compact form for the principle part, and how was it computed in the first place?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mvG22_40ZIvAr97xs8-UGX2TKOftzhsQ/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}2-e^z&=-2 (z-\log (2))-(z-\log (2))^2-\frac{1}{3} (z-\log(2))^3+\cdots\\&=-2(z-\log(2))\left(1+\frac12(z-\log(2))+\frac16(z-\log(2))^2+\cdots\right)\end{align}and therefore$$\frac1{2-e^z}=-\frac1{2(z-\log(2))}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac12(z-\log(2))+\frac16(z-\log(2))^2+\cdots}.$$Since$$z\mapsto\frac1{1+\frac12(z-\log(2))+\frac16(z-\log(2))^2+\cdots}$$is an analytic function near $0$ which maps $\log(2)$ into $1$, it can be written (near $0$) as $1+a_1(z-\log(2))+a_2(z-\log(2))^2+\cdots$, and therefore\begin{align}\frac1{2-e^z}&=-\frac1{2(z-\log(2))}\cdot(1+a_1(z-\log(2))+a_2(z-\log(2))^2+\cdots)\\&=-\frac1{2(z-\log(2))}+a_1+a_2(z-\log(2))+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a further question regarding the expansion of (2-e^z), and I apologize if it's silly since I just got into complex analysis. How was it expanded into -2(z-log2)-...? I assume it has something to do with the pole existing at z=log2 so (z-log2), but where did the -2 come from? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Given any analytic function $f$ and any point $x_0$ of its domain, the Taylor series of $f$ about $x_0$ is $f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}2(x-x_0)^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3+\cdots$. I applied this to $f(z)=2-e^z$ with $x_0=\log2$.